# ¿Como crear un usuario que no tenga la posibilidad de borrar las BD de Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, shell

He creado este tipo de usuario pero con el puedo hacer de todo
al hacer:

> lo que hago.

```
use database
db.logout()   -----------> para asegurarme que no este logeado con ningun usuario

db.auth("restrictedUser", "password") ---------------------->ingreso con el usuario sin privilegios


db.getUser("restrictedUser", { showPrivileges: true})
  {
        "_id" : "beatsapp.restrictedUser",
        "user" : "restrictedUser",
        "db" : "beatsapp",
        "roles" : [ ],
        "inheritedRoles" : [ ],
        "inheritedPrivileges" : [ ],
        "inheritedAuthenticationRestrictions" : [ ]
    }
```

> pero puedo crear y borrar

```
db.createCollection("test");
db.test.drop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando creas el usuario con [db.createUser(user, writeConcern)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/index.html)
, puedes definir el rol que le vas a asignar. En la sintaxis del método, **user** es el documento que define al usuario y tiene la siguiente forma:

```
{
  user: "<name>",
  pwd: "<cleartext password>",
  customData: { <any information> },
  roles: [
    { role: "<role>", db: "<database>" } | "<role>",
    ...
  ],
  authenticationRestrictions: [
     {
       clientSource: ["<IP>" | "<CIDR range>", ...]
       serverAddress: ["<IP>" | "<CIDR range>", ...]
     },
     ...
  ]
}
```

donde en el campo **roles** (array) van los roles otorgados al usuario. [Estos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#built-in-roles) son los roles disponibles: sin embargo tambien puedes definir [roles propios](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-user-defined-roles/#user-defined-roles).

En tu caso, sería, por ejemplo:

```
{
  user: "restrictedUser",
  pwd: "password",
  customData: { <any information> },
  roles: ["read","beatsapp"],
  authenticationRestrictions: [
     {
       clientSource: ["<IP>" | "<CIDR range>", ...]
       serverAddress: ["<IP>" | "<CIDR range>", ...]
     },
     ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: amigo he creado mi usuario con los roles espececificos y descubri que no funcionaban los roles hasta que inicie el servidor con el parametro --auth pero ahora tengo el problema de no puedo ingresar aun que mi usuario y contraseña si se encuentren en la  bd ("admin") y en la collection "system.users" pero al hacer auth siempre me niega el acceso no se que mas tengo que hacer

Comment: Puedes revisar los mensajes de log en el archivo **mongodb.log** para ver qué está pasando, luego puedes explicar mejor tu pregunta. Saludos !